# Manage files with scheme in XCode

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

I am new to IOS development and I am looking for a way to manage a file called hku.plist *(NOT info.plist)* with schemes.

What I want to do is use hku.plist in production scheme and hku.dev.plist in development scheme.

If this is not possible with schemes. What do you guy's recommend?

Comment: Have two separate targets with each having its own info.plist?

Comment: Thats the thing I have only one target one codebase multiple schemes and it is not a info.plist its a healthkit.plist I do know how to set up multiple info.plist in the same target.